# How to handle SSL Certificate Error in Selenium 3?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the code mentioned below but it is not working Chrome Version 79:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
//capability.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver//chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(capability); 
//driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Runtime.getRuntime().exec("AutoIT_Exe//AutoIT_Login.exe"); 
driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use *switches* to ignore such errors

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```